# Woocommerce HTML email option unavailable

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, email, html-email

I am attempting to create HTML emails in woocommerce.  I currently only have the plain text email option available.  I have added the following to `functions.php` on my theme:

```
function wps_set_content_type(){
  return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wps_set_content_type' );
```

As well I have installed the following php modules `php-gd`, `php-xml` and `php-xmlrpc`.  I have restarted apache after installation and verified that all modules are available.

The odd thing is that when I check the options locally, I have the HTML option.  When I check on the live server there is only the plain text option.  Locally I am running `PHP 5.6.14-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)` on the live server I am running `PHP 7.0.20 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2017 06:34:07) ( NTS )`.  Surely `PHP7` can handle this right?

Does anyone have a clue on what else I could try?

Comment: Then something else has gone wrong. The PHP DOM extension, php-xml, should be enough provided it's installed and enabled correctly. In php -a try `echo class_exists( 'DOMDocument' );` and you should see "1" printed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missing function argument. just try it.

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type','set_content_type');
    function set_content_type($content_type){
      return 'text/html';
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it is still not working.

Comment: It didn't work for me either